# Run a single job on GPU else use CPU in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am relatively new to programming and beginner at AWS cloud. I was wondering if there was a service\way that normally my code runs on CPU instance like t3.medium in AWS but when a certain condition is true (like a file gets available in bucket) then runs my function on a GPU instance like g4dn.xlarge. I want to do this so that I don't incur charges for continuously running my code on a GPU instance. The function that needs to be run is taxing as it takes up-to 7 minutes on google colab. I might be using it 20-30 times a day. Thanks.

Comment: Look in to EC2 AutoScaling, that can turn on and off a EC2 instance based on some kind of triggering event, you could set the default to 0 instances then scale up to 1 instance when your trigger is true.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see if it will be suitable.

Comment: Might be useful: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community ‍‍](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein ! I have got the general idea just trying to set those custom conditions.